# Sumar elementos únicos de un array con el framework de agregación en Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

talvez me puedan ayudar con esta consulta

He creadoo el siguiente código:

```
docu = { genres: "$genres" }
fase1 = {$match: {"actors":{$ne:"Undefined"}}}
fase2 = {$match: {"genres":{$ne:"Undefined"}}}
fase3 = {$group: { _id: "$actors", numgeneros:{ $sum:1 }, items: { $addToSet: docu } } }
fase4 = { $sort : {numgeneros : -1}}
pipeline = [ fase1, fase2, fase3, fase4]
db.genres.aggregate( pipeline )
```

que me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Harold Lloyd", 
    "numgeneros" : 236.0, 
    "items" : [
        {
            "genres" : "Short"
        }, 
        {
            "genres" : "Drama"
        }, 
        {
            "genres" : "Romance"
        }, 
        {
            "genres" : "Comedy"
        }
    ]
}
```

El problema es que lo que deseo sumar son los géneros únicos, es decir que numgeneros debe ser igual a 4 en el ejemplo no a 236.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré darle solución rápidamente, el tema estaba en añadir una nueva fase **$project** y hacer la cuenta desde allí con el operador **$size**

```
fase1 = {$match: {"actors":{$ne:"Undefined"}}}
fase2 = {$match: {"genres":{$ne:"Undefined"}}}
fase3 = {$group: { _id: "$actors", generos: { $addToSet: "$genres" }}}
fase4 = {$project: {"_id": 1, "numgeneros": { $size: "$generos"}, "generos": 1 }}
fase5 = { $sort : {numgeneros : -1}}
pipeline = [ fase1, fase2, fase3, fase4, fase5 ]
db.genres.aggregate( pipeline )
```

La salida es justamente lo que se pedía:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Dennis Quaid", 
    "generos" : [
        "Horror", 
        "Drama", 
        "Action", 
        "Thriller", 
        "Science Fiction", 
        "Crime", 
        "Family", 
        "Dance", 
        "Romance", 
        "Disaster", 
        "Biography", 
        "Comedy", 
        "Western", 
        "Adventure", 
        "Satire", 
        "Animated", 
        "Fantasy", 
        "Suspense", 
        "Sports", 
        "Musical"
    ], 
    "numgeneros" : 20
}
```